# Using variable Integer

Tags: android

I have a variable integer,I don't know how to use it

Here is my codes:

```
public class ImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ColorMatrixColorFilter cf;
    public static int level = Levels.level;

    public ImgAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
        matrix.setSaturation(0); //0 means grayscale
        cf = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix);
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return ThumbIds.length; // I want a way to add level after ThumbIds
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        int size = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.width);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setImageResource(ThumbIds[position]);


        return imageView;
    }

    public static Integer[] ThumbIds1 =
    {
        R.drawable.question1,
        R.drawable.question2
    };
    public static Integer[] ThumbIds2 =
    {
        R.drawable.question3,
        R.drawable.question4
    };
    public static Integer[] ThumbIds3 =
    {
        R.drawable.question5,
        R.drawable.question6
    };
    public static Integer[] ThumbIds4 =
    {
        R.drawable.question9,
        R.drawable.question10
    };


}
```

level is variable (1 or 2 or 3 or 4)

I want to add the integer level after ThumbIds (ThumbIdsX where x is the integer level)
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: uhh this is the exact same question as this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146442/variable-integer

Comment: Define a method `getCountForArray(int whatArray) { // use switch statement on whatArray and return the appropriate array's length }`. Add integer argument representing `whatArray` to `getCount()` and return value of `getCountForArray(whatArray)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of ThumbIds.

```
ArrayList<ThumbIds> list = new ArrayList<ThumbIds>();
```

So you can add to the array using push, and grab specific ThumbIds using get.